# Having Trouble drawing an oval to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am making a checkers game to help me learn GUI's with java. I am using a JLayeredPane boardAndPieces to hold 2 JPanels: board and boardPiecesPanel. board holds 2 more JPanels: boardPanel and boardButtonPanel. boardPanel is the checkers game board and, as far as I can tell, has no issues so far. boardButtonPanel holds several buttons used for play, but shouldn't be causing a problem either. Here is the relevant code:

`

```
boardAndPieces = new JLayeredPane();//a layered pane to hold the pieces and board panels
board = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());//A panel to hold the board and buttons
boardPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8));//the checker board. Within the JPanel board
boardPiecesPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,8));//The panel that will hold the pieces
board.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
boardButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));//holds the buttons used for play. Within the JPanel board
board.add(boardButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//...add to the board in this space. This works fine

boardAndPieces.add(board, Integer.valueOf(1));
boardAndPieces.add(boardPiecesPanel, Integer.valueOf(2));

//Draw initial pieces
boardPiecesPanel.add(new RedPieceDrawer);


//Class RedPieceDrawer looks like this:
class RedPieceDrawer extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(30, 30, 40, 40);

    }
}
```

`

Using this code, The buttons and checkerboard appear, but no circle or anything from boardPiecesPanel appears.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of basic issues...

1. Your `RedPieceDrawer` does not have any sizing hints that would allow a layout manager to make decisions about how best to layout this component
2. By default, `JLayeredPane` does not use a layout manager at all, meaning that when you add components to it, they have no initial size, meaning that won't render

With your current approach, you're also going to have issues with placing the checker pieces onto the board to begin with.

A better approach might be to simply create a series of panels that act as cells and then simply `add` the game piece directly to...

**For example**

[image: Checkers]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Checkers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Checkers();
    }

    private JPanel[] cells;

    public Checkers() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

                cells = new JPanel[8 * 8];
                int col = 0;
                int counter = 0;
                for (int index = 0; index < cells.length; index++) {

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    cells[index] = panel;
                    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                    panel.setMinimumSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
                    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }

                    frame.add(panel);

                    counter++;
                    col++;
                    if (col > 7) {
                        counter++;
                        col = 0;
                    }

                }

                int row = 3;
                col = 4;
                int cell = (row * 8) + col;

                cells[cell].add(new GamePiece(Color.RED));

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePiece extends JPanel {

        public GamePiece(Color color) {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBackground(color);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int dim = Math.max(getWidth() - 4, getHeight() - 4);
            int x = (getWidth() - dim) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - dim) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, dim, dim);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Now, if you're not up to doing cell translations, you could use a two dimensional array instead.

I would also be tempted to use a single `MouseListener` attached to each panel and/or game piece so you could manage the user interactions...

Answer (score 0):

Why extends JPanel? Just create a object that can draw itself:

```
public class RedPiece{

    //..ivars
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int w;
    protected int h;
    protected Color color = Color.RED;

    public void draw(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawOval(x, y, w, h);

    }
}
```

Then draw it on some JPanel:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (RedPiece p : pieces)
            p.draw(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: While I don't disagree, there are other benefits for using a component for this case, like localised mouse events, adding components directly to the cell...just saying